# How to extend sharestatus-page options?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

When I use the `ShareStatusTask`, the task only gets to share to social media the user has linked his account with.

How can I add an Email or even WhatsApp option, to share to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options on this page rely solely on the services user has his account linked to / apps installed on the device. In case you want to share to different locations you will need to implement your own logic.

There are however two simple ways to share built in the Windows Phone SDK – e-mail and SMS compose tasks

**E-mail Compose Task**

```
EmailComposeTask emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask();
emailComposeTask.Subject = "message subject";
emailComposeTask.Body = "message body";
emailComposeTask.Show();
```

This will open a new Mail app window with prefilled values. In case you want more control, you can add To, CC, etc. - see the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394003(v=vs.105).aspx

**SMS Compose Task**

```
SmsComposeTask smsTask = new SmsComposeTask();
smsTask.Body = "Test SMS";
smsTask.Show();
```

This opens the SMS app with data prefilled, so the user can edit and send it. Again more info here, on official documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394005(v=vs.105).aspx

Just a final note – you can't **force** the user to share by e-mail or SMS, because those are OS secured tasks, you can only prepare the messages and the user ultimately decides whether or not he wants to really send them.